# Calculate suspension oil needed for a fork?

Tags: fork, suspension, preventative-maintenance, recumbent

I've got a non-standard 20" air fork (Mekkem SASO) that could use some maintenance, but there's zero info I can find from either the manufacturer or OEM on oil viscosity, volume, or anything else. I've watched many air fork service videos, so  I'm confident I can follow those procedures for disassembly and cleaning since things aren't likely to be very different from a hardware setup standpoint, but after I drain,  I'll be stuck trying to figure out how much oil to put back in. It's got 80mm of travel, so I'm wondering if I should just eyeball it (3ml?) of "standard" suspension fluid (5w?) or if there's a standard way to calculate what you need by measuring the volumes of the tubes and going from there.

Given the lack of info on this item, I assume replacement parts will be difficult or impossible to acquire, so  I figure I should try to stay ahead of the wear to keep them around as long as possible. They don't get mountain-bike type use, just bad pavement and fairly tame single and doubletrack + gravel.

Comment: Keep trying to contact the manufacturer for an authoritative answer.

Comment: worst case scenario you can find the correct amount of oil by trial and error (too much oil and for will hardly compress, too little oil and there will be little to no dampening action).

Comment: I use w15 thickness (motorcycle suspension oil) and it works great for me, don't think it's super critical since w15 seams to work fine (for me at least), i'm using rock shox reba forks. It looks like rock shox uses w30 so you could go with that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a specific source, but in my shop we use a chart from RockShox that can be applied to almost every front suspention. [Here is a link](https://sram.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002313653-How-much-suspension-fluid-should-I-put-in-my-fork-)

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. [We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please use the [edit] button to summarize the information is contained in the link within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: Doubless that chart is copyright and reproduction here would be an issue.